# CRUD flutter/firestore/firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to coding and what I am trying to achieve is to set up a method that checks the 'MONDAY' collection inside post and if the data exist? the values of the fields get updated otherwise they get created! I have been stuck for a while now and been redirected to different solutions but nothing has worked for me. I appreciate all help

```
  Future<void> createPostMonday(Post post) async{
    await postsRef.document(post.authorId).collection('Monday').setData({
      'alOne':post.alOne,
      'alTwo':post.alTwo,
      'alThree':post.alThree,
      'alFour':post.alFour,
      'alFive':post.alFive,
      'alSix':post.alSix,
      'beOne':post.beOne,
      'beTwo':post.beTwo,
      'beThree':post.beThree,
      'beFour':post.beFour,
      'beFive':post.beFive,
      'beSix':post.beSix,
      'likes': post.likes,
      'authorId': post.authorId,
      'timestamp': post.timestamp,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[setData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) is used to write the contents of a single document whose ID you already know.  It requires that you use a [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) object to locate that document.

If you're trying to add a new document to a collection with a unique random ID, you should use [add()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) method of a [CollectionReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html).

```
await postsRef.document(post.authorId).collection('Monday').add(...)
```

Comment: hi @Doug Stevenson . thank you in advance. what i am trying to do is to crate a method that checks if the collection already exist ? update them otherwise create new. i have searched and been advised different solutions so i got here!

Comment: What you just said sounds very different than what you said in your post.  Please edit the question to be very clear about what you're trying to achieve.  Right now, all your question is just saying is that you have a compile error when trying to use an API.